# Smuggling my character out of the country

Tags: plot

In the story I'm writing, I'm planning on smuggling my character out of her country using an orchestra. My question is would a woman, about 5'2" be able to fit into a double bass' hard case? The orchestra is travelling by boat, and the country she's smuggling herself into is sympathetic to her.

Comment: In my youth, a school drama production - 'The case of the double-bass case' - was prompted by the availability of such a container.  I fitted inside quite easily.  Not sure about the ventilation for a long period though.

Answer (score 1):

The person would fit, but anyone lifting the case or anyone observing someone lifting the case would notice the difference in weight.

Comment: That's true!  I think double basses are around 40lbs, so there's definitely a difference.